# ggplot geom_text accept markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

I'm trying to add a label to a ggplot graph using geom_text. I can add the label correctly, but I can't get the label to use markdown. I need the text to follow statistical conventions.

```
ggplot(diamonds, 
   aes(carat, price)) + 
   geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
   geom_smooth(method="lm") + 
   geom_text(size=2.5, aes(x = 4, y = 4,
                      label=paste("r^2=", 0.34, "\n",
                           "gradient= ", 0.56, "\n",
                           "_p_=", 0.003)))
```

[image: output]

Comment: What `_p_` stands for?

Comment: Italic p. Using markdown notation

Comment: can you clarify whether you need the label to be italic (in which case A. Suliman's answer may solve your problem) or whether you specifically want ggplot to honor markdown notation (in which case your problem may be impossible, or at least very difficult)?

Comment: If it's impossible that's fine, I'll use the solution below. I take it that markdown isn't possible in a geom_text.

Comment: If you're OK with LaTeX formatting, you could either put something together with `label_parsed()` and the `latex2exp` package, or use TikZ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @missuse answer's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47124238/annotate-in-ggplot2-does-not-honor-newline-is-a-pasted-and-parsed-command), we can do

```
nonmetric_label = c(paste0("italic(R)^2 ==", 0.34),
                      paste0("gradient ==", 0.65),
                      paste0("italic(p) ==", 0.003)) 

ggplot(diamonds, 
         aes(carat, price)) + 
    geom_point(alpha=0.1) +
    geom_smooth(method="lm") +
    annotate("text", x = c(4,4,4), y = c(6500,3250,500),
             label = nonmetric_label , parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: So basically the answer is not to use geom_text and to use annotate instead. You can get the formatting correct in geom_text by using parse=TRUE, but it doesn't like the \n

Comment: Yes, but you can you use \n in geom_text as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43063744/how-to-display-text-on-several-lines-with-geom-text-in-faceting-wrap)